# issues with Makefile in C

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

```
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------    ------
# Choose a compiler & its options
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

CC   = gcc
OPTS = -W -O3

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Add the debug flag to compile for use by a debugger
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#DEBUG=-g

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Add the names of the directories
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
SRCDIR= src
OBJDIR= obj
INCDIR= include
BINDIR= bin

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Add the rest of the source files. Don't forget to add the '\' character
# to continue the line. You don't need it after the last source file
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
SRCS=$(SRCDIR)/Lab12.c \ Function1.c \ Function2.c \ Function3.c \                                   Function4.c \          Function5.c 

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# You don't need to edit the next few lines. They define other flags
# used in the compilation of the source code
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
INCLUDE = $(addprefix -I,$(INCDIR))
OBJS=${SRCS:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o}
CFLAGS   = $(OPTS) $(INCLUDE) $(DEBUG)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Add the name of the executable after the $(BINDIR)/
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
TARGET = $(BINDIR)/ Lab12

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS) 
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ $(OBJS)

$(OBJS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS)

 cleanall:
    rm -f $(OBJS)
    rm -f Lab12

 #--------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Add a target named cleanall that will remove the object files as well
 # as the executable
 #--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have all my "header" files in the include folder. I have all my source code in the src folder (Lab12.c , Function1.c, Function2.c ...). I keep getting this error when i use the make command.

Makefile:45: target `Function1.c' doesn't match the target pattern
Makefile:45: target` Function2.c' doesn't match the target pattern
Makefile:45: target `Function3.c' doesn't match the target pattern
Makefile:45: target` Function4.c' doesn't match the target pattern
Makefile:45: target ` Function5.c' doesn't match the target pattern
gcc -W -O3 -Iinclude  -c  -o  Function1.c
gcc: no input files
make: *** [ Function1.c] Error 1

I cant quite figure out why it is behaving this way. All these files are in the src code folder so why isnt the system recognizing them?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the formatting in my post. In the original Makefile. Function4.c and Function5.c are present.

Comment: In oder to paste lines together, the backslash must be the last character on a line; there mustn't be any other character, not even whitespace, between the backslash and the end of the line. You can put various objects on one line, but then you don't have to separate them with backslashes.

Comment: If `Function1.c` and so on are in `$(SRCDIR)`, you must prepend the directory to these files, too. (Or you don't specify `$(SRCDIR)` with any of the files and make a pattern substitution later.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SRCS=$(SRCDIR)/Lab12.c \ Function1.c \ Function2.c \ Function3.c \
```

seems wrong; you should try

```
SRCS=$(SRCDIR)/Lab12.c Function1.c Function2.c Function3.c
```

instead

**UPDATE**

If Function1.c and so on are in ´$(SRCDIR)`, you must prepend the directory to these files, too. (comment from M Oehm)

Comment: Or put them on separated lines, each -except the last one- ending with a backslash

Comment: I changed the line with the suggestions made in this post. However, I still get the error message. What exactly do you mean by prepend the directory?

Comment: SRCS=$(SRCDIR)/Lab12.c $(SRCDIR)/Function1.c $(SRCDIR)/Function2.c $(SRCDIR)/Function3.c

Comment: @JohnDoe : Please accept the answer if it has answered your question. You can accept the answer by clicking the check mark beside OznOg's answer. Thanks, and welcome to StackOverflow!